# Discontinuity in the frequency-domain response when input is a sine wave

Tags: fft

I have simple sine wave as input $x(t) = \sin(6\pi t)$ and then take a Fourier transform of the signal. Afterwards, I multiply that to a transfer function. I see a discontinuity 3GHz. Is this just an artifact?
$
Y(\omega) = G(\omega)\cdot X(\omega)
$

where $G(\omega) = \frac{-j\omega}{\omega_m^2(1+j\eta) - \omega^2}$
[image]

Comment: That needs a lot more detail. A sine wave is just  a sine wave. There is no carrier unless you modulated something. Did you do this. Your frequency axis also does not make any sense. The frequency of $\sin(3t)$ is about 0.5Hz, your axis is in GHz.

Comment: The number three is angular frequency indeed but that doesn't change the core problem.

Comment: Reza, would you mind being more explicit about how you're representing $x(t)$ in the computer and then computing and displaying the spectrum?  Because the question, as shown, is a pencil-and-paper description of a problem.

Comment: when you say "$x(t) = \sin(6\pi t)$", do you mean that $t$ is time, expressed in nanoseconds?  Is this a 3 GHz sine wave?

Comment: By the way, can you please fix your title?

Comment: I think the title is great.

Answer (score 3):

You know the Fourier transform of the sine: $\mathcal F\{\sin (3x)\}(\omega) = \mathrm{i} \left(\delta(\omega - 3) - \delta(\omega + 3)\right)$ (nonwithstanding some real scalar factor depending on your  normalization of the Fourier transform). That is a distribution that's zero in all but two points on the real axis.

If you multiply with something that is zero almost everywhere, the result should be zero almost everywhere.

Your result is *not* zero, almost everywhere!

So, whatever you did was **not** multiplying with the Fourier transform of a sine. Otherwise, there could only be two frequency components.

So, no, this is not just an artifact. You must have mixed up something during your calculations!

Comment: Marcus, I ain't happy about this answer.  First paragraph is, to say the least, misleading.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson I might not be having my brightest day; is this about the fact that the plot is a sampling of Fourier space and not actually continuous?

Comment: There are two discrete frequencies that have non-zero energy.  But this is a continuous-time question and then it **does** have a continuous-frequency spectrum.  $X(\omega)$ is just two dirac delta functions with some scaling constant.  But the continuous-frequency spectrum has zero value everywhere else.  But the spectrum is **not** discrete, it's defined for continuous frequency.  Then the multiplication by $G(\omega)$ should result in the same dirac delta functions with different scaling constant.

Comment: @MarcusMüller anything you plot on a computer is inevitably discrete. I am not sure what you are implying here. The final results of the calculations which is the time-domain response of the system (not shown here) makes sense and matches experiments so I am not making mistakes along the way.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson fair point. I should fix that. But I think the point – point-wise multiplication of a continuous function with two diracs can't give anything but two diracs – still stands

Comment: @RezaAfra see the comment directly above. You know the Fourier transform of the sine – it's two diracs: zero almost everywhere. Now, you multiply two diracs with whatever $G(\omega)$ is, and get something that isn't zero almost everywhere. Tells me you didn't multiply.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson went back and fixed stuff. Thanks for the feedback. My late-night answer was really shoddy.